# How to Serialise a byte array into AVRO in Java?

Tags: avro

I am trying to **serialise array of bytes in avro**.
But, I am getting ClassCastException during the process. Any help for the same would be highly appreciated.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection ([B and java.util.Collection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Here is my **schema**.

```
{
  "name": "my-data",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "bytes"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your byte array into ByteBuffer e.g : ByteBuffer.wrap(your_byte_array). This is what causing ClassCastException.